# Search that the elements of an array exists in the other -PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if the array number 1 exists in the array 2 using php, I tried in_array, but i didn't get any result :/

## 1

```
array(
(int) 0 => '2',
(int) 1 => '3'
)
```

## 2

```
array(
(int) 0 => (int) 1,
(int) 1 => (int) 2,
(int) 2 => (int) 3
)
```

Please if anyone can help :)

Thank you !

Comment: Check `array_intersect` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_intersect will work for you. Try this :

```
$array1 = array(
(int) 0 => '2',
(int) 1 => '3'
)

$array2 = array(
(int) 0 => (int) 1,
(int) 1 => (int) 2,
(int) 2 => (int) 3
)

$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

if($result)
{
// exists
}
else
{
// not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [0=>'2',1=>'3'];
$array2 = [1,2,3];

echo "<PRE>",var_dump(array_intersect($array1,$array2)),"</PRE>";
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```